Android Chrome Bowser (Mobile Browser) does not detect SSL
The website is hosted on Apache.
SSL is in place and no problem with certificate. It is valid.
The issue is that Android Chrome Browser (Mobile Browser) does not detect SSL with the setting "Always use secure connections" turned on.
On inputting NAKED DOMAIN, "truesellerwebstore.com" It gives a message, "The connection to truesellerwebstore.com is not secure".
(By the way chrome prefixes "http://" to all naked domains.)
I have tried various code combinations on .htaccess without any success.
Current .htaccess is reproduced, kindly suggest.
The goal is to achieve https://www.truesellerwebstore.com which ever the input url INCLUDING NAKED DOMAIN.
Tried various combinations on .htaccess without any success.
Following is the relevant extract.
ENFORCING SSL
<IfModule ssl_module>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests;"
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
</IfModule>

Enforcing HTTPS
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests;" env=HTTPS

REDIRECT TO HTTPS
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^truesellerwebstore\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.truesellerwebstore\.com$
RewriteRule ^\(\.\*\)$ "https\:\/\/www\.truesellerwebstore\.com\/" [R=301,L]

REDIRECT HTTP TO HTTPS
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http\:\/\/truesellerwebstore\.com\/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^\(\.\*\)$ "https\:\/\/www\.truesellerwebstore\.com\/" [R=301,L]

REDIRECT TO WWW
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^truesellerwebstore\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.truesellerwebstore.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>


The browser cannot somehow "detect" SSL. It tries both, unencrypted and encrypted protocol. If your browser first tries the unencrypted protocol despite that setting then that is a browser bug, not a programming issue. If your redirection does not work (the first two attempts look fine, the rest is rubbish), then that is your actual issue. You will have to debug that: 1. is a redirection sent or not (check your server's access log file and if not, then why not (check your server's error log file, maybe enable rewrite logging on the server side).

By the way chrome prefixes "http://" to all naked domains. That seems unlikely, but I don't have a way to test this.

The best approach to create a default https domain is using the https DNS resource record. AFIK all modern browsers understand it and directly default to the protocol configured in this record. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/HTTPS_RR

Can "https DNS resource record" be added to cpanel ? Please let me know the procedure. Let's try this also . . .

To test prefixing of http:// just type the naked domain into the browser address bar and then touch to copy and there you will find that "http://" has been prefixed by chrome.

For arkascha, the issue is only with Android Chrome, other browsers like Firefox etc redirect seamlessly to the https version with the setting "Always use secure connections" is turned on. On Android Chrome too if the setting "Always use secure connections" is turned OFF it resolves.
